# Accessing scripts inside IIS virtual directory

Tags: coldfusion, iis-6

I have an IIS 6 server with a virtual directory pointing to a network share on another machine. That web server also serves ColdFusion scripts. When I access regular HTML pages that reside in the virtual directory, they are served properly. Anytime I try to get to a ColdFusion script, however, ColdFusion throws a "File not Found" error.

Am I missing a step? Is there something else that I have to do in ColdFusion to tell it where the files in that virtual directory actually exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like you may need to alter the permissions that ColdFusion runs under and that right now it does not have sufficient permissions to access the network share.

To change the permissions or user CF runs under:

1. Open Services
2. Find the CF Service (depending on your version it might start with Macromedia...)
3. Right Click, Open Properties
4. Click on Log On
5. Then either change the account it logs on as or change the permissions for the current user.
6. Click OK, Apply, etc...

I'm pretty sure you will have to bounce the CF Service.

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I overlooked that. I spent so much time fiddling with permissions in IIS that I completely forgot about the CF service.